# Why is the html from a ajax call different when inspecting data and data as Jquery object

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm trying to refresh some part of a page with an async call with JQuery. Part of the code you can see here.

```
success: function (data, status, xhr) {
              var $result = $(data);.....etc
```

Now when I inspect 'data' and '$result' the HMTL-strings are not the same. For example:

Snippet from data:

```
<div class='divLoading'>
        <img src='/Content/Icons/load.png' />
    </div>
    <div class='divGridContent'>
        <div id="divGridMenu" class="divGridMenu">
            <div id="divGridMenuContent" class="divGridMenuContent">
```

This is 'good' HTML, but when I inspect $result:

Snippet from $result:

```
<DIV class=divLoading><IMG src="/Content/Icons/load.png"> </DIV>
<DIV class=divGridContent>
<DIV id=divGridMenu class=divGridMenu>
<DIV id=divGridMenuContent class=divGridMenuContent>
```

How can this be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it's because of this statement:

```
var $result = $(data);
```

This will turn $result in a jquery object not an html string. This will probable return a normal html string:

```
var #result = $(data).html();
```

But in that case, you could also this:

```
var $result = data;
```

Comment: I tried that before posting, but it didn't work. I probably didn't refresh my javascript file. When I use your code to get some part of $result like this `var $selectedElement = $result.filter($(elementName));`. Following the example form the jQuery site (`$("div").filter( $("#unique"))`) I get an error _Object doesn't support this property or method_.

Comment: I marked your solution as the answer, but it only solved part of my problem. So I asked a new question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7176541/selecting-from-jquery-success-result]